# How to prevent G+ to show animal posts on my timeline

Tags: google-plus

I know that G+ learns what you like/see, and even though I have never, ever, clicked (given focus) on an animal post (90% cats, 9% dogs, 1% other animals) shown on my timeline, most of the time I wait for the animation to load, so the harm is equally done.

I have never joined an animals group or anything similar, but they show on my timeline more often every week. Same with super cars, and lately with road bikes.

How can I stop G+ suggesting (it does well!!) and inserting on my timeline subjects I have not explicitly joined or subscribed?

Comment: Convince the people in your Circles not to share so many?

Comment: they belong to a group or community  "WOA Animal" I don't belong to. How can blacklist it?

Comment: I have the same trouble with Instagram. I ended up unfollowing a good friend because he follows a bunch of celebrities that I cant stand. We keep in touch via facebook instead.

Comment: @designerWhoCodes ok, that could be the case. Thanks to you both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a partial solution but it could be the best we can do with G+ today:

1. Partition the G+ accounts you follow into circles `read1` (first priority), `read2` (second priority), `read3`, ... as many as you want. Put all the "WOA Animal" community into the final circle, we'll call it `readBewareOfAnimals`.
2. Expand **Circle Streams** in the left column, click on `read1`, and read that circle first. This circle should contain the accounts you most want to read, not accounts that are too verbose for your tastes.
3. When you have additional time, read the `read2` circle and maybe move on to the `read3` circle.
4. Once in a while, zip through `readBewareOfAnimals`. That way you won't totally miss what those friends post but you won't have to face fuzzy faces the rest of the time. It's considerably less spammy when you know what you're diving into.
5. You can put the same accounts into various circles organized for you to post to, e.g. `Friends`, `Family`, `Acquaintances`, `Just Following`, ...